# Deleting a node in an ordered linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on an ordered linked list in C++. The task is to delete notes from the list and I've got two methods / functions to do that.

```
/*
 * delete_head: Auxiliary function that deletes the first node of the list.
*/
book *delete_head(book*& deleteNode){
    head = deleteNode->next;
    delete deleteNode;
    
    return head;
} 

/*
 * delete_node: Method that deletes a node from the list. 
 */
 void delete_node(int c){
     book *aux = head;
     
     // Verify list isn't empty.
     if (head != NULL){
         // Case 1: the head should be deleted.
         if (aux->code == c){
             head = delete_head(head);
         } else {
             book *aux2 = head->next;
             while (aux2 != nullptr && aux2->code < c){
                 aux = aux2;
                 aux2 = aux2->next;
             } 
             // Case 2: node wasn't found.
             if (aux2 == NULL){
                 printf("Error: Node doesn't exist. \n");
             } else {
                 // Case 3: the tail should be removed.
                 if (aux2->next == NULL){
                     aux->next = NULL;
                     delete aux2;
                 } else {
                     // Case 4: A node from the middle should be removed.
                     aux->next = aux2->next;
                     delete aux2;
                 } 
             } 
         } 
     } else {
         printf("Error: Empty list. \n");
     } 
 }
```

I've tested the code and the cases in which I delete the tail of the list or a node that's in the middle do work. The one that's giving me a bit of trouble is the case in which I need to delete the head and I'm not sure if it's related to the way pointers are handled.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and explain what trouble you are having

Comment: for a *minimal* example you could remove all code for the cases that are working and to make it complete you could add code that actually calls the function to delete the head

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code with a debugger? If not, then please do that.

Comment: Unrelated, but Case 3 and Case 4 are logically identical.  Your code would be more compact and readable if you used only Case 4 and removed the unnecessary test for `aux2->next==NULL`.  Also, avoiding `printf` in this kind of function makes it more useful.  If you need to report that a node couldn't be deleted, why not have the function return a value that indicates this?  Then if a caller needs to know that the node wasn't found, it can do whatever it wants (including printing a message if that's appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper function is borked:

```
book *delete_head(book*& deleteNode){
    head = deleteNode->next;
    delete deleteNode;
    
    return head;
}
```

You call it with `head = delete_head(head);`, but when you do that `deleteNode` is set to a *reference* to the pointer to head. This means that anything you do to `deleteNode` you also do to `head` - and vice versa.

This means that here: `delete deleteNode;` you delete *both* `deleteNode` and `head`, which is a bit of a problem as you then return `head`.

Change the function to `book *delete_head(book* deleteNode){` and it should do what you want.